# TypeScript issues when creating ref for React Native TextInput

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-ref

I came across an issue when defining refs i.e.

```
inputRef = React.createRef(null)

//...

const someFunction () => {
 if (this.inputRef && this.inputRef.current) {
   this.inputRef.current.focus()
 }
}

//...

<TextInput ref={inputRef} />
```

When I access `.focus()` I get following error:

> [ts] Property 'focus' does not exist on type 'never'. [2339]

Can I somehow tell `createRef` that this ref can be `null` or `TextInput` so it knows that `.focus()` may exist?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
inputRef = React.createRef<TextInput>();
```