# React Native : Not able to switch to next TextInput on returnKeyType="next" using ref

Tags: typescript, react-native, focus, use-ref, react-native-textinput

I am trying to move the focus from one `TextInput` to another on keyboard next press like in the below code in typescript

But it shows *"Property 'focus' does not exist on type 'never'.ts(2339)" error*

Is there any other method to do the same functionality

```js
const emailRef = React.useRef()
const passwordRef = React.useRef()

<TextInput
     ref={emailRef }                             // Current TextInput Ref
     onSubmitEditing={()=>passwordRef .current?.focus()}  // Changing focus
     secureTextEntry={isSecured}
     placeholder={placeHolder}
     placeholderTextColor={GREY[400]}
     selectionColor={GREY[900]}
     style={styles.inputText}
     onChangeText={onChangeText}
     keyboardType={keyboardType}
     onEndEditing={onEndEditing}
     autoFocus={autoFocus}
     returnKeyType={returnKeyType}
/>
```

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53390679/typescript-issues-when-creating-ref-for-react-native-textinput

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
inputRef = React.createRef<TextInput>();
```

Comment: Working fine 